# Latex enumerate overwrites the first item label over the second, so that the a and b are on top of each other

Tags: enumerate, labels

```
\begin{mdframed}[innertopmargin=6bp, innerbottommargin=4b, innerleftmargin=8bp, backgroundcolor=yellow!10, nobreak= true]
    \begin{thm}
    \label{thm:them2}
        {Assuming that the sizes of the matrices allow for the  operations, the following rules of matrix arithmetic are valid}
        \begin{enumerate}[nosep, label=(\alph*)]
            %\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
            \item $A + B = B + A$ \; \textit{Additive Commutativity}
            \item $A + (B + C) = (A + B) + C$ \; \textit{Additive Associativity} 
            \item $A(BC) = (AB)C$ \; \textit{Multiplicative Associativity}
            \item $A(B+C) = AB + AC$ \; \textit{Distributive Law}
            \item $(B+C)A = BA + CA$ \; \textit{Distributive Law} 
            \begin{multicols}{2}
            \item $a(B + C) = aB + aC$ 
            \item $(ab)C = a(bC)$ 
            \item $a(BC) = (aB)C = B(aC)$
            \item $A + 0 = 0 + A = A$
            \item $A - A = 0$
            \item $0 - A = -A$
            \item $A0 = 0$ and $0A = 0$
            \end{multicols}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{thm}
\end{mdframed}
```

Comment: please provide an example that shows the problem, including all needed packages

Comment: And removing unneeded packages.  Do you still have the problem if you take away the `mdframed` and `thm`?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't start with a list, but with `{Assuming ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need some additional packages which were presumably missing from your unshown code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}


\begin{mdframed}[innertopmargin=6bp, innerbottommargin=4bp, innerleftmargin=8bp, backgroundcolor=yellow!10, nobreak= true]
    \begin{thm}
    \label{thm:them2}
        {Assuming that the sizes of the matrices allow for the  operations, the following rules of matrix arithmetic are valid}
        \begin{enumerate}[nosep, label=(\alph*)]
            %\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
            \item $A + B = B + A$ \; \textit{Additive Commutativity}
            \item $A + (B + C) = (A + B) + C$ \; \textit{Additive Associativity} 
            \item $A(BC) = (AB)C$ \; \textit{Multiplicative Associativity}
            \item $A(B+C) = AB + AC$ \; \textit{Distributive Law}
            \item $(B+C)A = BA + CA$ \; \textit{Distributive Law} 
            \begin{multicols}{2}
            \item $a(B + C) = aB + aC$ 
            \item $(ab)C = a(bC)$ 
            \item $a(BC) = (aB)C = B(aC)$
            \item $A + 0 = 0 + A = A$
            \item $A - A = 0$
            \item $0 - A = -A$
            \item $A0 = 0$ and $0A = 0$
            \end{multicols}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{thm}
\end{mdframed}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works like a charm.